# reactjs a function in other component got called, how come

Tags: reactjs

**update 1**

```
class Buddies extends Component {
 @autobind
    isBottom(el) {
        if(el === null || el === undefined || el[0] === null || el[0] === undefined)
            return false;
        return el[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight;
    }

   componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
        this.getBuddies();
    }

...........
```

As you can see isBottom() is called when scrolling happening in MyBuddies component. What makes it interesting is I'm not even using this component when I'm on Timeline component.

So I just wonder how is isBottom() even triggered across different components??

---

Interestingly, a function isBottom() in ComponentA is called after another component ComponentB is loaded.
The relation between them is paralleled.

```
 <Switch>
           ...
           <Route exact={true} path="/buddies" component={MyBuddies} />
           <Route exact path='/buddies/:userName' component={Timeline} />
 </Switch>
```

MyBuddies composes a list of Buddy components. A button in the Buddy component will lead user to Timeline component.
This is the button:

```
<Link to={`${match.url}/${fullNameNoBlanks}`}>Glance</Link>
```

As you can see that the Timeline component is more like a detailed page which comes after the MyBuddies page.

**What I want to fix is, when Timeline page(component) is loaded, there should not be any functions or variables from MyBuddies is accessible in Timeline.**

I thought this is by default, but somehow the odd thing happened.
Is it because I did something in a wrong way?

Comment: Can you show your MyBuddies component and how is isBottom in MyBuddies called

Comment: Since there is not enough details, my guess is both components are shared the same store. One solution is to isolated the store from Timeline, so Timeline get its data in componentDidMount and does not update anything in the main store.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Hi thanks for your help. I have updated my question with more code.

Comment: @LeekInPajama I'm not even using any stores. not using Redux or MobX either. It's just a easy learning Reactjs project.

Comment: @Franva Not sure is this cause the problem. But it looks like you never unbind global event listener. Try adding clean up code to `componentWillUnmount(){ window.removeEventListener(...)}` hook.

Comment: You need `window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)`. The condition in `isBottom` can be written as `if (el && el[0]) { ... } else return false;`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko make sense~! since it's bound to the window object so the function isBottom() becomes a global function! I will remove it in componentUnMount(), thanks~!

Comment: @LeekInPajama thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks mate, that's the cue, proved! Can you please post your comment as an answer? So I can mar it as my solution. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding global event handler that never gets removed.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    this.getBuddies();
}
```

To fix this you need to remove scroll listener when component is umnounted using `componentWillUnmount` hook

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
```

Comment: @Franva Glad I could help